# Table layout with same height cells in every row

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a table layout which in every row, two neighbor cells should have same height. I thought that the `display:table;` and `display:table-cell` should automatically handle this layout but the result seem similar to a **two-column** layout and **mansory effetc** which every cell has its own height.

I tried removing `float:right` but it brings all cells into one row.

```css
.newsTable {
  display: table;
}

.lastAnchor {
  display:table-cell;
  float: right;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="inner newsTable">
 
 <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>
  
   <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. 
 </a>
  
   <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>
  
  
   <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `float` option, which takes the elements out of the document's normal flow, and also add in another wrapper element, to act as the `table-row`

```css
.newsTable {
 display: table;
}

.lastAnchor {
    display:table-cell;
 /* Remove this float: right; */
 font-size: 9pt;
 width: calc(50% - 10px);
 margin: 5px;
 vertical-align: top;
 padding: 5px;
 border-top: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
 padding-top: 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
/* For 2 column layout */
.row {
  display: table-row
}
```

```html
<div class="inner newsTable">
  <div class="row">
 <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>
  
   <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. 
 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>
  
   <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works but needs hard coding of table rows on every two element.

Answer (score 1):

You might use `flex` layout:

```css
.newsTable {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.lastAnchor {
  flex: 1 0 45%;
  font-size: 9pt;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #aaaaaa;
  padding-top: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class="inner newsTable">

  <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>

  <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. 
 </a>

  <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum.
 </a>

  <a class="lastAnchor">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea aperiam convenire eam, quodsi tritani ex qui. Et cum case doctus argumentum, semper feugiat rationibus eum ei. Cu hinc fugit accommodare per, ex exerci volutpat repudiare eum, tale novum percipitur ius cu. An mea nemore convenire, te quo indoctum hendrerit. Vocent nostrud platonem ei sit, vim ut mucius minimum, ea sed qualisque vulputate. Epicurei persequeris mediocritatem id sit, cum labitur conceptam ut. In utamur appellantur ius, ex integre electram vix, no per ponderum suscipiantur.
 </a>

</div>
```